# Horizontal Asymptote & Range

Tags: calculus, functions

Suppose y = c is a horizontal asymptote of a function y = f(x). Is it true that the number c does not belong to the range of f(x)?

Answer (score 1):

No. A simple example would be f (x) = 1/x for x> 0 and f (x) = 1+x for x <= 0.

Then 0 is horizontal asymptote but 0 is in the range.

Comment: Nice example! Next, let's keep aside the piece-wise defined functions - can we say that a function will NEVER touch/intersect its vertical asymptote?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: study a function $f(x) = \frac 1x \sin x$ when $x\to \infty$.

Comment: Great example! So this means a function may or may not touch/intersect its horizontal asymptote, right?